# Open Browser in background in android

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to load a download url into a browser which automatically download a file using the browser into deafult download folder.But when i load the url into the browser in my app it automatically open the browser.

```
mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
mWebview .loadUrl(fileMetadata.getWebContentLink());
```

Is there any way to load the URL into the browser but it will automatically close after loading the url. I dont know the way there should be in way i think.
Can anyone tell me how to do this in android??

Comment: If you are using a URL that downloads the file than you should use DownloadManager. It will start downloading process in background.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download a URL in the background then you should use DownloadManager. It will download your file in the background. More information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

Comment: But i need to open the url into a browser . @SuperThomasLab

Comment: @kkkk Why if you want to download it in the background then you need to use downloadmanager. If you open it in the browser then it is visible to the user.

Comment: Is it possible to close the browser to after download the file using the url?? @SuperThomasLab

Comment: @kkkk if you want to downalod it in the background you will need to use downloadmanager.

Comment: @kkkk then your `minSDKVersion` should be `9`.

Comment: Is there any way to close the browser after downloading ?? Do u know anyway??? @SuperThomasLab

Comment: @kkkk you mean the default browser app?